# How to define and use opencv mat of user type

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

My question is similiar to the one [a cv::Mat of std::vector ... how do I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760149/a-cvmat-of-stdvector-how-do-i)

I need a matrix where each element is a std::vector.  This matrix is the output of calculations done on a series of images of the same size (like a video ). Many of the calculations are typical cv functions (convert to gray scale, box filter etc. ) and the value of the pixel is then added to the vector. I do not know before hand how many images I will have and in any case, I cannot use the channel concept as images may be more than 512.

One of the suggested answers there was to use a Mat of pointers.  So if I try the following, will it work?

This will be on Windows machines and I understand that the pointer size INT-PTR 64 bits wide. I could then use CV_64 but only CV_64F is defined.  Since I will not be doing any calculations with this matrix, can I use this to store the pointers. I am thinking that before I read the first image, I will get the size, create this matrix, use "new std::vector" to create the vector for each pixel and store that pointer in the element.  In the loop for my calculations I use the same access offset for to read the original images and to store the output in the vector.   When I am done with the vectors, I need to delete these before I release the cv::mat.

I appreciate any input from those who know more about opencv than I do - this is really from the first application with opencv.

Comment: Given that this is your first OpenCV application, may I suggest that putting your user type into a matrix might not be what you want to do?    Can't you instead create a user type that stores matrices of ordinary values, and then store a vector of those, where each vector element represents the result for one frame?

Comment: As in the example I cited, I need quick access to all the data in the third dimension. a vector of matrices will not give this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
cv::Mat_<your_type>
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id7

In particular:

```
To use Mat_ for multi-channel images/matrices, pass Vec as a Mat_ parameter
```

There's a nice example, and you can use your own "blend" of [Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec)
(assuming the size of the array/vector for each element is fixed), or if you really need you can use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you!  This should do it.  Since I will not know at compile time (and actually before the calculations at run time), how many images I will have, I cannot use a vector of known size.  I will try Mat_ and update here of my success.

Comment: Here is what I did - and it appears to be working as intended. <br> typedef std::vector<WORD> MyVector, *LPMyVector;<br>cv::Mat_<LPMyVector> m_matPtrs;<br> At the beginning, I allocate these vectors and use it in my calculations. This allows me to process images using opencv functions and store results in this matrix in the same loop.<br>Once agan Thank you.